# How can I set the default image used when my page is shared on Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I had tried something I saw on a blog using meta tags as such, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://foo.com/bar/2.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="150">
```

Comment: Is it solved already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the recommended open graph tags, I also include a link tag:

`<link rel='image_src' href='https://example.com/path/x/file.ext' />`

(with the same uri as og:image content="uri")

Answer (score 0):

You don't need type, width, or height, but you have to add some other fields to get this to work correctly. Example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Online Advertising"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://nextlocal.ca/img/logo320.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NextLocal"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="NextLocal's advertising produces long-lasting results and comes with a guarantee, making it a great investment for your business."/>
```